# E: Malformed entry 52 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)

Tags: apt, 18.04

I get this error in Ubuntu Studio 18.04 LTS. What can I do to fix it as I am not able to update my system.

```
"E: Malformed entry 52 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)"

cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Studio 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
```

Thanks,
Raoul

Comment: Please run the following command and then edit your question to show the output of the command. Thanks! `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Thanks, unable to put the output here as it says I dont have the reputation to add more than certain number of links (which are in the output)

Comment: Please paste the output, then highlight the entire output, and then press CTRL+K and save your changes to properly format the output as code so that it does not recognize the code as links. Thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, that helps. The answer below should fix the malformed line. If the answer fixes your issue, don't forget to click the check mark icon to the left of the answer to mark the answer as the accepted solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 52 appears to be this line

`deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main`

It should be

`deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main`

Run the following command to fix this problem:

```
sudo sed -i 's|/bionic|/ bionic|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly! Your guidance is much appreciated! Regards,Raoul